# Listing files in a directory within a Jade template

Tags: html, node.js, directory, pug

I am currently using the Jade HMTL templating language (used in conjunction with CodeKit) to generate my site. One of the pages of my site needs to be an index of all the pages within specific directory. Rather than manually keep this updated I would quite like to have the generated automatically.

Is there a way within my Jade template to create a list of the all the files in a geven directory? Is it possible to embed some script that could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exclusively with Jade, but you can pass Jade that info from Node.js.

This example assumes you are using Jade with ExpressJS, but you can adapt it as necessary:

Node.js:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  fs.readdir(path, function(err, data){
    res.render('index', {"files": data});
  });
});
```

Jade (index.jade):

```
ul
  for file in files
    li
      p= file
```

Comment: Thats perfect. Any idea how to get this working in a CokeKit environment (I understand this might not be ideal).

Comment: Are you precompiling Jade into static HTML? Or rendering Jade templates with node.js? Are you building a node.js site?

Comment: I am precompiling into static HTML.

Comment: Ah, then, no. There's no way to do what you want. Jade is templating engine - it has no ability to access the file system. And as far as I can tell, CodeKit has no support for passing data into the Jade compiler. You tagged the post with node.js - where are you using node.js?